# How to build and use the kernel of the Rpi I2C to 1-Wire Bridge DS2482?

Tags: i2c

Like the post on Oct 2013 by AnyNC I to would like to use the DS2482 module in a C program on my Pi but I'm unsure how and where to get further information on this.  All the reply links to his post are dead.  Any help please.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/108140/edit) your question and provide a link to the post you are talking about?

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111412/owfs-one-wire-file-system-can-at-most-detect-four-ds18b20-sensors-connected-to